# Call to ggplot in a function with NSE

Tags: r, ggplot2, func, nse

The idea is to patch a call to ggplot in a function.

The example:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(lazyeval)

df <- data.frame(A=letters[1:10], B=2:11, C=3:12))

func <- function(name, dat=df) {

  output <- dat %>%
    select_(~A,name) %>%
    arrange_(interp(~desc(var), var=as.name(name)))

  plot <- 
    ggplot(output, aes_string(x=reorder(~A,-name), y=B)) +
    geom_bar(stat='identity')

  print(plot)
  return(plot)

}

result <- func("B")
```

Compiling gives:

> Error in -name : invalid argument to unary operator.

I tried `deparse` and `substitute`. Not sure I got the right combo. Any ideas?

Comment: I’m not sure what purpose the `reorder` is even supposed to serve here — it seems like you’re attempting to plot `B` against mismatched `A`. That’s not a good idea, and I don’t think ggplot supports it.

Comment: @@Konrad: see this previous [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32681370/ggplot2-x-axis-ordering-unresolved) for what `reorder` resolves.

Comment: Ah I see, that makes sense. However, the fix for this is straightforward, isn’t it? Simply reorder the factor outside the `ggplot` call.

Comment: I tried :-) to no avail, so far. Care to share a way to do? Thanks

Comment: Yeah, turned out harder than I thought. Anyway, take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Reorder the data before passing it to `ggplot`. The following code also moves some of the column names around in the `ggplot` call, because otherwise you’d always be plotting `A` against `B`, regardless of the `name` argument — or was that intentional?

```
function (dat, name) {
    var = as.name(name)
    reord = list(interp(~ reorder(var, -var), var = var))
    output = dat %>%
        select_(~A, name) %>% # Not actually necessary.
        arrange_(interp(~ desc(var), var = var)) %>%
        mutate_(.dots = setNames(reord, name))

    plot = ggplot(output, aes_string(x = 'A', y = name)) +
        geom_bar(stat = 'identity')

    plot(plot)
    plot
}

func(df, 'B')
```

I’m using the `mutate_(.dots = …)` form here. Have a look at dplyr’s “NSE” vignette for more information on its usage.

Comment: @@Konrad: the only re-ordering needed is after `output` is obtained to force ggplot to break alphabetical tying when plotting. So far I found this chunk to work: `ggplot(output,aes_string(x=quote(A), y=B) )+...` as in the question. Now, how to do the reordering with reorder??

Comment: @remi Well, you’d *still* do it as in my answer.

Comment: @@Konrad: sorry, well it actually doesn't produce the needed outcome. I think it is the call `mutate_` that messes things. Basically, we have to make `dat$A <- reorder(dat$A, -dat$name)` executable in the local env. just before calling ggplot.

Comment: @remi Do you actually want to reorder `A` rather than what ever `name` is? If so, the code is easily adapted, just change the `mutate_` statement to `mutate_(A = interp(~ reorder(A, -var), var = var))`.